# Uploading images to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: postgresql, image, google-cloud-platform

I am hosting my web app on Google Cloud Platform. In this app, users can upload photos (along with other information to make a post). I am using a Postgresql database, and it appears I cannot directly upload images to my database on GCP. There is a tutorial I found here: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/uploading-images-directly-to-cloud-storage-by-using-signed-url for using Signed URLs to upload to Cloud storage, but I was wondering if there were any more straightforward methods? The tutorial seems a bit involved with generating signed URLs and creating specific buckets for the user to upload/receive images to/from. Thank you!

Comment: I would think it could be done programmatically. What runtime is your app using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more straightforward way would be something like this (you didn't specify your environment, so this example is in python):

```
    from google.cloud import storage


def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # source_file_name = "local/path/to/file"
    # destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print(
        "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(
            source_file_name, destination_blob_name
        )
    )
```

The Cloud Storage [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) has more examples in different languages as well